# Do I need to know good javascript in order to use jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prerequisites

I do not know javascript right now but I am planning on learning it. My question is do I need to have a good understanding of javascript in order to use jquery? I already know actionscript and php which are quite similar. Should I study javascript before learning jquery?

Comment: Strange question. jQuery is a javascript library. It's a bit like asking if you have to have a good understanding of PHP to use codeigniter.

Comment: Hmm. Good one. But can I get away with just some basic knowledge of javascript syntax but not really know in-depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you need to to with *jQuery*..

of course it helps but most basic operations can be done just calling functions of the framework itself with selectors like:

```
$('#elementId').hide()
```

So quick answer: yes, you should but until you don't need complex control flow over jquery you can do simple things just with basic syntax.

**EDIT:** of course without knowing how to attach functions to elements, or how to execute functions when document is loaded you can't do anything, so these basic things are essential before any kind of jQuery usage.

Comment: I’d add that if you’re doing anything non-trivial with jQuery, you really need to learn JavaScript, so that you’ve got an understanding of what’s going on.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not, although it wouldn't hurt.  Chances are, if you learn jQuery, you'll also wind up learning Javascript along the way.

Comment: +1. Even knowing some javascript, learning how to use JQuery, Prototype, and other JS libs can do a lot to teach you more.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery helps you to use the more advanced aspects of Javascript without a deep knowledge of it. However, it would be helpful for you to get a general overview before you dive in to jQuery.

Comment: I would say just the opposite. It helps you do the mundane things more easily, but unless you have a good understanding of it and the DOM, you're going to lean in the direction of the trivial.